# PowerMock and Mockito not working for TestNG

Tags: mockito, static-methods, powermock

I have a utility class with a static method

```
public class A {
    public static boolean test1(){
           // Do something
           return true;
    }       
}
```

I am trying to mock test1 using Powermockito and using TestNG for testing

```
@PrepareForTest(A.class)
public class UnitTest{

   @Test
   public void testTest1() {
      PowerMockito.mockStatic(A.class);
      when(A.test1()).thenReturn(false);
   }
}
```

https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/TestNG_usage
Describes me to do this way.

However, in "when(A.test1()).thenReturn(false);"  it calls the actual method test1() during the Mockito.when setup for test1() method. Hence, I believe the setup is not done right where it cannot recognize Class A as a Mock

Am I doing something wrong here?

My dependencies in pom.xml -

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
   <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
   <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
   <artifactId>powermock-module-testng</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.2</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Maybe the PowerMockTestCase inheritance is missing?

@PrepareForTest(A.class)
public class UnitTest extends PowerMockTestCase {
    ...
}

Comment: @DamienBeaufils Yes. That Solves it. More info - https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=54#c9 . Thanks for guiding me. I tried to google more and came to this issue and it was also in the comments section of https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/TestNG_usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the comment from  @Damien Beaufils, I tried to google more and finally found a post in the **powermock** issues; The google group describing the same problem.

The solution is that your test should extend `PowerMockTestCase` (which is imported from the `testng powermock module` i.e `org.powermock.modules.testng`)

More info - [code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=54#c9](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=54#c9)